# How can I set a window to a specified scale，just like window+tab do

Tags: winapi, scale, hwnd

I have a native window and I know it's HWND，how can I scale it just like window+tab do.
That is, I want to embed a window to my own application and scale the window to fit my application's size.
Thanks.

[window+tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j74t.jpg)

Comment: Your analysis is wrong (Flip3D does not set the scale of a specific window), and based on that you are asking a question, that doesn't make sense. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I want to embed a window to my own application and scale the window to fit my application's size.

Comment: It gets worse... you cannot safely, in a controlled way, re-parent a window. This isn't going to work out (see [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) for more information). You will have to look into another solution.

Comment: Those images posted are bitmap images of windows, they are not the actual window. You can take picture of a window and flip it and squeeze it, but you can't mess with the actual window like that. By the way, Windows has given up on that flip thing, it's disabled in Windows 8 and 10.

Comment: See the [DWM Thumbnail API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969541(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: DWM maybe useful. Thanks.